# Can't use panel with transformation as source panel

Tags: grafana, panel, transformation

I am new to grafana and exploring…
I have a dashboard which has panel A.
I have created panel B with data_source as panel A and applied many Transformations and visualizing it as time series ( has 3 columns)
Now, I am trying to add one more panel (panel C) whose source panel should panel B.
But, I wouldn’t able to select panel B in the drop down ,
How to resolve this issue without executing all the transformations and effectively
Thanks in advance

To get panel B as source panel to panel C